# "Prehistoric Science" Fallacy

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-religion

Is there an accepted name for the kind of argument (or its refutation) that goes something like:

> Our ancient texts speak of weapons that could annihilate the entire
> world, and of flying saucers, proving that nuclear and aviation
> technology was well-known to our ancestors, but got lost with time..

I'm asking this in the context of Indian mythology, which is ripe with these kind of fantastic stories, and has always provided harmless comfort to the religious but now forms the basis of junk arguments for Hindu nationalism. Having the appropriate term for this kind of reasoning will allow me to search for how other thinkers have effectively talked about this issue and add it to to my arsenal.

Comment: I'm reminded of [The Sirius Mystery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sirius_Mystery). Maybe reading some of the associated criticism will turn up a good name for this kind of thinking.

Comment: Search for "ancient astronauts".

Comment: An efficient rebuttal for this type of claim is to point that no archeological evidence whatsoever of those technologies have been found. The explosion of the Tsar Bomba left marks still visible to this day. Remains of our modern technology will be identifiable for the millenniums to come (and nuclear power plants waste for the next 100.000 years !). If our ancestors had such technology, we should expect to find traces in archeological sites, not pottery or stone masonry. (By efficient I mean able to convince the bystanding audience. Nothing will make your opponent admit they are wrong)

Comment: @armand - one line I've taken in the past is that any sufficiently advanced technology would have had to go through sufficient iterations of varying success such that it's extremely unlikely that traces of that evolution are completely wiped out while all that remains is a final convenient account of its use in a polished literary saga. It's much easier to write stories than to collectively realize these achievements. You offer an excellent concrete example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [idola tribus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idola_tribus), 'idols of the tribe', or a tendency of human nature to prefer certain types of incorrect conclusions:

> "And the human understanding is like a false mirror, which, receiving
> rays irregularly, distorts and discolors the nature of things by
> mingling its own nature with it." -Francis Bacon in Novum Organum,
> describing this fallacy

I immediately thought of Atlantis mythology, used in a similar way

Comment: Thanks @CriglCragl. I think this is the closest to what I was looking for so I'll mark this as the answer. I was hoping that someone had come up with something memorable like Dawkins's "Argument from personal incredulity" :)

Comment: @VineetBansal: The 'argument by lack of imagination' is my favourite. This work by Bacon is among the most foundational works of scientific method, and his points deserve special attention.

Answer (score 1):

There are a suite of fallacies at work here.  Wishful thinking, invalid references, cherry picking evidence, and failure to look for any refuting data.

You will find this suite of fallacies, plus at times almost everything else found on a fallacies reference list, deployed by almost any propagandist or ideologue. Both often are well aware these are fallacies, hence when challenged they will generally just post alternative fallacies or falsehoods pointing to the same conclusion.

The point is that ideologues and propagandists do not arrive at conclusions based on reasoning or evidence, they instead deploy "reasoning" selectively to justify a pre-selected conclusion.

Refuting fallacies to an ideologue or propagandist has very limited effect.  The primary benefit will be for any observers of the interaction, for whom an intellectually honest discussant can demonstrate the intellectual DIS honesty of the propagandist or ideologue.